# Account address in ethereum wallet already existed

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, wallets

**My etherum got stolen today**

I have hosted my own ethereum fast node. The node wallet has multiple account. I have created a mini app with api to create new account(without passwords) for users, also allowing them to deposit and withdraw ethreum.

When I did "*eth.accounts*" (about a month post hosting the node) in my wallet (from geth command line) I was surprised to find 3 addresses with transactions **dating 2 months even before I created the node**(source etherscan.io).
**Please note the following**:

- I have hosted the node on AWS ec2, and storing data by attaching a volume. Note around the time of those unknown transaction i had another node with this same volume attached. 
  Is it possible that the node somehow picked up wallet accounts from the previous node?
- Node is running on a docker container ([client-go](https://hub.docker.com/r/ethereum/client-go/))

How did these accounts get into my wallet, when i know the probability of generating an already generated address is almost 0? Could there have been a hack, inserted these addresses into my wallet, making users think these are new?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, account private keys are stored in node's data directory in `keystore/` subdirectory and are easily transferable from one node instance to another.  If you didn't clean up your data directory after previous node, then your accounts were picked up by the new node.

Comment: Only if you operate your system by unlocking your account on the node to begin with (instead of signing the transaction yourself and sending it to the node).